# ERROR - new Global exception handled! Message = java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.math.BigInteger

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hql, jpql

DataType of patientId is BigInteger in entity Object

```
private BigInteger patientId;
```

Code:

```
    @Override
    public List<ChatRoomHistory> getLastChatDetails(List<String> patientIds) {
    String queryStr = "FROM ChatRoomHistory where type = 'NO' and patientId in :patientIds ORDER BY chatCloseTime DESC";
    TypedQuery<ChatRoomHistory> query = sessionFactory.getObject().getCurrentSession().createQuery(queryStr, ChatRoomHistory.class);
    query.setParameter("patientIds", patientIds);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Error

```
    2020-08-16 19:52:27,939 [http-nio-8080-exec-5:] c.t.c.u.e.GlobalExceptionHandler.handleException:243
                ERROR - new Global exception handled!    Message = java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.math.BigInteger
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.math.BigInteger
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.BigIntegerTypeDescriptor.unwrap(BigIntegerTypeDescriptor.java:19)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.DecimalTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(DecimalTypeDescriptor.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:280)
```

Comment: You are sending `List<String>`  for `patientIds` is not valid I think, you should send `List<BigInteger>`

Comment: I tried with BigInteger as well but getting           ERROR - new Global exception handled!    Message = java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.math.BigInteger
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.math.BigInteger

Answer (score 0):

Like said in the comment, you can't pass a list of String as a parameter intended for a numeric field.

You should declare your parameter as

```
public List<ChatRoomHistory> getLastChatDetails(List<BigInteger> patientIds)
```

Comment: I tried same but getting : ERROR - new Global exception handled!    Message = java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.math.BigInteger
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.math.BigInteger

Comment: Can you show the entire code ? Is there some place where you declare a LinkedHashMap ?

Comment: List<BigInteger> patientIds = mapper
       .readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(thpResponse.getResponseData()), List.class); 
                                                                                                     
                                                                                                     
 List<ChatRoomHistory> chatRoomHistory = chatHistoryDAO.getLastChatDetails(patientIds);

Comment: I meant the whole class please.

Comment: @Ramanuj Don't use `List.class` rather use `List<BigInteger> patientIds = mapper .readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(thpResponse.getResponseData()), new TypeReference<List<BigInteger>>(){});`

Comment: I've not used  LinkedHashMap anyWhere all are premitive and Wrapper type

Comment: ERROR - new Global exception handled!    Message = Cannot deserialize instance of `java.math.BigInteger` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (String)"{"managedAccountsUserIds":[59630,60289]}"; line: 1, column: 1] (through reference chain: java.lang.Object[0])
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.math.BigInteger` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (String)"{"managedAccountsUserIds":[59630,60289]}"; line: 1, column: 1] (through reference chain: java.lang.Object[0])

Comment: @Ramanuj that means you there is problem in json, your ids in `managedAccountsUserIds` node . You can check you is your query working or not by passing some constant id in query first.

Comment: In constant working fine:  select * from ChatRoomHistory where patientId in ('55630','90289') and type = 'GP' ORDER BY chatCloseTime DESC;

Comment: @Ramanuj Please show us minimal code to reproduce you problem then. For your code your json should be like `[59630,60289]` or you need to create a class with field `List<BigInteger> managedAccountsUserIds`

Comment: @Ramanuj See here details https://onlinegdb.com/SyM2l0LGP

Answer (score 0):

You can correct your method in this way:

```
@Override
public List<ChatRoomHistory> getLastChatDetails(List<BigInteger> patientIds)
{
    String hql = "select c from ChatRoomHistory c where c.type = 'NO' and c.patientId in :patientIds ORDER BY c.chatCloseTime DESC";
    TypedQuery<ChatRoomHistory> query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql, ChatRoomHistory.class);
    query.setParameter("patientIds", patientIds);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Comments:

1. Even though HQL does not require the presence of a `select_clause`, it is [generally good practice](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-select) to include one.
2. *The list of values must not be empty; it must contain at least one value.* (See [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-in-predicate)).

Comment: List is not empty : but gettign o-8080-exec-2:] c.t.c.u.e.GlobalExceptionHandler.handleException:243
    ERROR - new Global exception handled!    Message = java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.math.BigInteger
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.math.BigInteger
 at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.BigIntegerTypeDescriptor.unwrap(BigIntegerTypeDescriptor.java:19)

Comment: Is this stack trace somehow **related to** the method `getLastChatDetails` execution?